# How to override the onTouchUp in the user control which can be used to fire the event not only on this user control, but whole application

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I am a new to the C# and WPF. Right now, I want to override `onTouchUp` event in my user control. Then I can add user control in the references for reuse. The problem is each time I want to test this event on the application, the event only fires at area of user control, not whole screen. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: can you briefly describe your scenario? basically, you could get reference to a window in which is your usercontrol used and attach to PreviewTouchUp event

Comment: Maybe I am wrong,  basically, I need a user control(maybe not) can be reused in any of application layer. which I don't need override event again.  So I override the onTouchUp event, only add message.show("test"). Then I add this user control into reference of my application. after I add this user control in my application, only I touch up the area of user control, the message "test" will pop up, if touch out of that area, there is no reaction. I want to my user control can react event not only the area of user control, but i also need fire event on the whole screen area.@Liero

Comment: in that case you shoulod write just plain class, that contains the behaviour. The class will need reference to an UiElement on which you want to handle events, which is probably MainWindow in your case. I recommend you to write the behaviour as attached property. It will be very convenient to use. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to attach to PreviewTouchUp event on a element, that covers the interactive area. It may be application wndows as well. Handling mouse or touch events outside window is not recommended.

Here's an example, how can you attach any behaviour to any element directly in xaml:

```
  <Window  my:MyBehaviour.DoSomethingWhenTouched="true" x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow">



public static class MyBehaviour
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty  DoSomethingWhenTouchedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DoSomethingWhenTouched", typeof(bool), typeof(MyBehaviour), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( DoSomethingWhenTouched_PropertyChanged));

    private static void  DoSomethingWhenTouched_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiElement = (UIElement)d;

        //unsibscribe firt to avoid multiple subscription
        uiElement.PreviewTouchUp -=uiElement_PreviewTouchUp;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue){
            uiElement.PreviewTouchUp +=uiElement_PreviewTouchUp;
        }
    }

    static void uiElement_PreviewTouchUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        //you logic goes here
    }

    //methods required by wpf conventions
    public static bool GetDoSomethingWhenTouched(UIElement obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(DoSomethingWhenTouchedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDoSomethingWhenTouched(UIElement obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DoSomethingWhenTouchedProperty, value);
    }
}
```